# We have a product to ship on iOS with some leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

In about 2 mins, there are about 9K of leaks as indicated by Instruments.  In about 1/2 an hour of use, there are about 235K with 6645 individual leaks.

I hate to even consider this but the code is out of my hands.  Would anyone even consider shipping a product in this state, or is this an acceptable rate for the iPhone and iPad?

Comment: I have shipped and Apple has approved an app with 4 MBytes of intentional leaks (memory debug code that accidentally wasn't removed in the production build).  Later fixed in an update, but not a single customer reported a crash in the interim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is horrible, you should absolutely not release any app with even 1/100th of the leaks yours produces. I would personally never ship anything with this many leaks. I try to make sure there are at least 0 leaks before shipping my products; I would suggest you (or someone who has access to the code) go through the code thoroughly and eliminate those leaks to the best of your programming ability. Eventually, your app will start crashing a bunch of times and Apple may likely even pull it once they get 100 or so crash reports of the leaks.

Comment: Even more important is that it is for our sales team.

Comment: Guess where they are?  In the YAJL JSON parsing for the Three20 library.  Guess why I have to use Xcode 3 to build it?  The Three20 library.  I find it very hard to stomach that we were delivered a product like this from a major supplier.  It's not going on the App store, but to our sales force.  I can't even build it on the device without 100 ARMV7 architecture errors.

Answer (score 4):

I'd strongly recommend fixing the worst offenders before shipping. Users are *brutal* with ratings and it is nearly impossible to "recover" from a spate of hateful 1-star ratings in nearly every rating system I've ever seen. The decision to ship early could haunt your team for years.

Comment: Totally agree. Do whatever you can to get the code back into your hands. If a manager is holding it then make the business case to them that sarnold states, i.e., it will cost them money in the long run. To be honest, you can get most of the leaks eradicated with one day of coding if you use the Analyze feature.

Comment: Yeah, I ran reports in Instruments and Analyzed and our contracted programmer said "I really don't know what to do with this".

Answer (score 0):

Follow up.  In the token parsing code, in the dynamically linked code, the vendor had commented out the release on the "facet" that they had allocated to parse the returned data.  Every dataset that was returned from the server (as an http string) was kept in memory.

Looking back, I should have been able to find it, but understanding that it took the vendor a while to makes me feel a little less sucky.

Thanks for looking at this.  Cheers.